# Creating a frame that can read Python and convert it to HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html

Hi all this is my first post as I have exhausted google and am asking for a little bit of help.

I'm a school teacher and I'm creating an ELearning website for my school, at present I'm attempting to create a code window where my students can input some python syntax and onlick the code is converted and shown in the adjacent window. Very similar to what is used in W3schools for its examples and various elearning websites.

Does anybody have any knowledge as to where I should start or have any links about creating this? I would probably go along the lines of when the 'submit code' button is pressed, a javascript object is created of the user input code, then rendered into the adjacent result box using some sort of ajax.

Thanks all for your kind, regards Andrew

Comment: what on earth do you mean "can read python and convert it to HTML"? ......python is nothing like HTML. You can't "convert" python to HTML. Python can *render* html, with some kind of framework, but... your question at present makes no sense.

Comment: though if you meant *render* html, yes, probably a reasonable thing to do would be to use an ajax call to post the code to a python framework, render the html server side, and then return an html response to the ajax call which would then inject the response into the dom.

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to StackOverflow. First of all, I recommend you to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), because this kind of questions are very unlikely to ve solved here. Try searching more information about the problem you have (e.g., take a look at the source code of W3Schools) and then, if you have a concrete programming question, there's no problem with asking it here. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, my apologise for the unorthodox question

Comment: "converted and shown"?  On w3schools it *executes* the code.  If you want that try something like [codepad.org](http://codepad.org).  Don't reinvent it.

Comment: an option can also be Ipython notebook (ipython.org)

Comment: @user2141414 Check out [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html), it visualizes your python code execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a page with an iframe, call it `result`. Then create a simple `<form>` and give the form tag an attribute `target="result"`. Include a textarea in your form. Your students' code is transfered to the webserver via a simple `form submit`. Then when your server produces an HTML response it is rendered in the iframe.

No javascript is needed. KISS!

Comment: be careful though not to give your students too much power over your webserver using python though :)

Comment: just a quick question? Will I require some sort of python plugin for the server to render the python into the iframe. As i have been looking into using Flask tho this requires primarily using a server written in python.

Comment: If your webserver is running Apache you will need to install the mod_python module(/plugin). Python also has a built-in webserver called SimpleHTTPServer, which might serve your purpose at first. Of course you need to write a python script that executes your students' python and returns its result as HTML. Only allow your students from within a certain IP range and run the python on a restricted user.